# Should we display a banner to warn about our policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: discussion, status-review, generative-ai

Stack Exchange has announced that [sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/162827). This banner could help prevent low-quality AI-generated posts from being posted in Movies & TV SE.

As discussed in this meta post: “[How should we deal with AI-generated posts?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/1006)”, the community consensus is that AI-generated content are banned in Movies & TV SE.

We could opt for this banner text option:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Movies & TV Stack Exchange. [Learn more](https://example.com)

What are your thoughts? Should we request that this banner be enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

Having decided against the use of AI/LLM generated content, the least we can do is warn potential answerers that this is now the case.

Regretfully, we cannot rely on users reading Meta to discover this information.